# Non 24 hour sleep cycle species and Star Trek

Tags: star-trek

Considering how humans have developed a 24 hour sleep cycle due to the Earth's rotational period and our natural diurnal circadian rhythm, and star fleets human only club attitude dictating social norms, how do other species adapt?

Unless Vulcan and Kronos have the same day/night cycle as Earth, the species from these planets would not be accustomed to our day/night cycle.  How do they handle the change?

This is asking about Non-humans on Star Fleet ships, which tend to be a "human's only club".

Comment: In the Trek 'verse, all the humanoid species were seeded from the same stock. It's not too much of a stretch that all humanoids live on planets with similar climates and rotation periods, leading to similar sleep cycles.

Comment: There appear to be at least 5 questions here. You need to tighten this up. Are you asking about ship-board life, duty rosters, whether other planets have differing rotational periods or what?

Comment: They are all connected...

Comment: I had always thought that "Starfleet" was the human contribution to the Federation's defense force; other species contribute their own fleets, crewed by their own people. Starfleet is unusual in allowing other species to join.

Comment: Vulcans are stoic. They would take the Star Fleet shipboard time in stride. Romulans, however, would simply take the ship over and adjust the time accordingly.

Comment: @cde - Can you show an example of a species being forced to adapt to human diurnal patterns, for instance?

Comment: If I did, I wouldn't need to ask. But in real life,  look at the mars rover teams who had to adapt to Mars time (40 minutes longer each day adds up). Or how wolves and cats, mainly nocturnal or crepuscular have become diurnal through human contact as dogs.

Comment: @cde Your question remains unclear. Are you asking about what happens when aliens visit Starfleet vessels, or are you asking about sleep cycles on board the alien vessels? I would assume individual sleeping quarters could be set to duplicate the daily cycle of any guests or prisoners taken aboard the larger Starfleet vessels.

Comment: Edited to narrow.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually very little canonical to go on, honestly.

The NX era (2150s) and the NCC-1701 era (2260s) both show us relatively unmixed crews. NX-01 had only two aliens (T'Pol and Phlox), while NCC-1701 had only **one** alien (Spock) until after its refit. Neither *Star Trek: Enterprise* nor *Star Trek* [classic] ever once broached the subject. Both, however, suggested at various times that Vulcans, at least, have greater control over processes that, for humans, would be entirely autonomic. This suggests that Vulcans might be able to adjust their sleep cycle accordingly. The NCC-1701-D era suggests that starships now have more integrated crews, but still never seems to talk about this issue.

On the flip-side, Bajor is glossed to have a 26-hour day, and both Deep Space 9 and *Defiant* run on this schedule, requiring Terrans to adjust accordingly. Nobody ever mentions having a problem doing so, however. They simply seem to accept it as a fact of life.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is, the attitude is "suck it up and deal with it".

Comment: Actually, I think the attitude is, "Star Trek isn't about sleep deficit disorder" :-) Page through the many questions that have no answers and you're left with the inescapable conclusion that the writers just never cared enough to answer them. It wasn't what the show was about.